# Android confirmation message for delete

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add a confirmation message box for delete.

How to do that in android?

Comment: Google for Alert Dialog in Android. And you will be provided with very good results.

Comment: Check this to know the reason http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/163525

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
private AlertDialog AskOption()
{
    AlertDialog myQuittingDialogBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this) 
        // set message, title, and icon
        .setTitle("Delete") 
        .setMessage("Do you want to Delete") 
        .setIcon(R.drawable.delete)

        .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) { 
                //your deleting code
                dialog.dismiss();
            }   

        })
        .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        })
        .create();

    return myQuittingDialogBox;         
}
```

**Calling**

```
AlertDialog diaBox = AskOption();
diaBox.show();
```

Answer (score 12):

You should do that with [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which){
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            //Do your Yes progress
            break;

        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
            //Do your No progress
            break;
        }
    }
};
AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ab.setMessage("Are you sure to delete?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
        .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
```